# AWS CLI list only the name of current running cloudformation stacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I'm building up to a larger AWS CLI job but one of the building blocks is stumping me;

**How do I get a list of just the names of every currently running AWS Cloudformation stack?**

I can list the stacks just fine with the following, but I can't get a query to pair it down to just the stack name.

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks --stack-status-filter CREATE_COMPLETE --output text
```

I could cut the resulting table down in bash, but I'd love a more elegant aws solution if it exists.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add the query parameter to that same query to narrow the result set to only the StackName.

Per @idbehold, you will also need to include all stack status filters except for `CREATE_FAILED` and `DELETE_COMPLETE` to truly capture all current stacks. These only need to be delimited by spaces.

**Query:**

```
"StackSummaries[*].StackName"
```

**Full Example:**

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks --stack-status-filter CREATE_IN_PROGRESS CREATE_COMPLETE ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS ROLLBACK_FAILED ROLLBACK_COMPLETE DELETE_IN_PROGRESS DELETE_FAILED UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS UPDATE_COMPLETE UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS --query "StackSummaries[*].StackName"
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation -  aws cloudformation list-stacks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-stacks.html)
- [AWS Documentation - Controlling Command Output from the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)

Comment: StackSummaries was the missing key there - how'd you know that was the value you needed so I know what to look for next time?

Comment: Great! Each AWS CLI command's documentation page has a listing of the output object you can expect. StackSummaries is the top level object, listed here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-stacks.html#output

Comment: Ahhhh, gotcha. That's good to know going forward, thanks! I'll accept once the 5mins are up.

Comment: @Alex this won't cover all currently running CloudFormation stacks. Namely your `stack-status-filter` should include [all statuses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-stacks.html#options) **except** for `CREATE_FAILED` and `DELETE_COMPLETE`. You especially don't want to miss out on stacks whose status is `UPDATE_COMPLETE`.

Comment: @idbehold You...have a good point, faulty logic on my part. Back to the drawing board to figure out how to do that then, thanks for the shoutout!

Comment: It's really too bad the AWS CLI doesn't provide a `--stack-status-ignore` option.

Comment: Done. Thanks @idbehold!

Comment: If I could double accept I would, thank you both for the help!

Comment: To avoid listing all possible status flags except CREATE_FAILED and DELETE_COMPLETE one can do a clientside query instead ``aws cloudformation list-stacks --query 'StackSummaries[*] | [?StackStatus!=`CREATE_FAILED` && StackStatus!=`DELETE_COMPLETE`] | [*].[StackName]' --output text``

Answer (score 0):

```
    # foreach stack in prod describe stack resources
    while read -r stack ; do \
    echo -e "\nSTART $stack\n" ;\
    aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --stack-name $stack --profile prd ; \
    echo -e "\nSTOP  $stack \n" ; done \
    < <(aws cloudformation list-stacks --stack-status-filter CREATE_COMPLETE \
    --query "StackSummaries[*].StackName" --profile prd \
    | perl -ne 's/\s+/\n/g;print'| sort)
```